# Cisco spanning tree configuration

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree

I need your support for my spanning tree configuration. I like to bridge my public network to a server and give him a public IP. I am using a virtual wire at the firewall to forward the public network. Later I connect the server to the vlan 123.

I have enabled spanning-tree rapid-pvst on my switch. Should I disable spanning-tree for vlan 123 to prevent a bpdu error shutdown. Is that enough?

thanks a lot[image: network]

Answer (score 0):

Spanning tree is used in order to avoid loops between interconnected switches.

Your diagram and description lacks quite some fundamental information. You have placed a L3 switch in with port with VLAN 123, therefore I assume that this port is meant to be a routed port instead of a switched port. In which case there is no need to use STP at all.

Do you have anymore switches in the network that you did not visualise? What made you think of using STP at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

CISCO switches have STP open in default. If you don't change it I think you will not face with a problem. Though not so information you gave, you can create a STP just for VLAN123 too. If you have more switches you need to submit a more detailed topology.